# Exiting From a Function in C++

Tags: c++, function, exit

Ok so I'm writing a code for the confirmation of a username and a password. I'm using linked lists to save the information and I'm prompting the user for the username and password which the code should confirm.

I honestly don't know what's wrong with this code

It works perfectly fine when I enter a correct username or password.

But if its wrong the first time and then I enter the correct information, the code acknowledges its correct and then asks for the correct password again.

```
bool List::enterConfirmation(string username, string password, int check)
{
    string userName;
    bool a;
    while (check <= 3)
    {
        ADMINNODEPTR p, q;
        for (q = 0, p = listPtr; p != 0 && p->username != username; q = p, p = p->next);
        if (p == 0)
        {
            cout << "\tInvalid Username. Try again\n\tUsername: ";
            cin >> userName;
            check++;
            enterConfirmation(userName, password, check);
        }
        if (p != 0)
        {
            a = confirmAdmin(p, password, 0);
        }

        if (a == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    cout << "You have exceeded your limit of tries." << endl;
    return false;
}

bool List::confirmAdmin(ADMINNODEPTR p, string password, int check)
{
    string passWord;
    while (check <= 3 && check != -1)
    {
        if (p->passsword == password)
        {
            cout << "Identification Confirmed" << endl;
            check = -1;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            cin.ignore();
            cout << "\tERROR: Incorrect Password. Please Try Again\n\tPassword: ";
            getline(cin, passWord);
            if (check < 3)
            {
                confirmAdmin(p, passWord, check);
                /*return false;*/
            }
            if (check > 3)
            {
                cout << "You have exceeded your limit of tries." << endl;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I had originally made the code much much shorter, neater and in one function but the fact that the function won't exit (even where I'm returning a value) is driving me insane. Please help if you can.

Thank you

Comment: In `confirmAdmin()` not all code paths return a value.

Comment: It might be clearer if you changed `if (a == true) { return true; } else return false;` to `return a;` in `enterConfirmation`.

Comment: You should probably not use recursion and a while loop in confirmAdmin(). Your recursive call should return the true / false if you do..

Comment: @drescherjm I know that but that doesn't mean the compiler should go back into the function after going to the closing bracket.

Comment: Unrelated: `cin.ignore();` in front of `getline(cin, passWord);` in `confirmAdmin` is a probable source of bugs. Generally It's better to place `cin.ignore` after the operation that left data you want ignored in the stream than to place `ignore` before another, unrelated, operation. The better option always removes the unwanted data from the stream, but the way the program has been written, it may remove wanted data from the stream if no unwanted data was left in the stream. If you find later that the first character of an input is missing, this is probably why.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for the tip. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: confirmAdmin doesn't have a return statement after the loop. When `check == -1` (or the loop terminates otherwise) execution will flow off the end and cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes I noticed that and added it to the code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
bool a;
```

`a` is not initialized. And it does not get initialized if the input fails validation, before it gets used. It only gets initialized by the call to `confirmAdmin()`, and only if the correct input is provided.

`a` ends up being used without being initialized first. Undefined behavior.

There are also execution paths in `confirmAdmin()` that do not return a value from that function, so `a` may be still uninitialized even in that case. Even more undefined behavior.

Comment: I changed the code; initialized a and made sure all the execution paths return a value and its still making the same error.

Comment: Nobody can help you with code that's not shown. You will need to post a new question that contains the new version of your code, and make sure it is a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help].